# android: create SurfaceView and add with addView()

Tags: android, surfaceview

*Update:*
I am finding that the simply the creation of SurfaceView is failing. If I add it at the end of the views - addView (surface, params) - it immediately blacks out the screen without the animator code segment executing. I have also tried creating it in XML. Same result.

---

I have a RelativeLayout and, during runtime, am attempting to add a SurfaceView to it. The view is added but it doesn't "punch through" as the documentation says. If I change the order to put it on top, I get a black screen.

Here's the code where it's added, which is called shortly after the constructor executes (in this rendition, the view is "on bottom" and I don't see anything happen):

```
surface = new SurfaceView (getContext ());
int w = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
int h = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams (w, h);
addView (surface, 0, params);
```

And, here's code where I try to display something:

```
animator.addUpdateListener (new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener()
{
  public void onAnimationUpdate (ValueAnimator animation)
  {
    zoomScale = (float) animation.getAnimatedValue ();
    Canvas canvas = surface.getHolder ().lockCanvas ();
    canvas.scale (zoomScale, zoomScale);
    canvas.drawBitmap (folderToZoom, 0, 0, null);
    surface.getHolder ().unlockCanvasAndPost (canvas);
  }
});
```

Putting a breakpoint in the latter code, I can see that the SurfaceView is of the correct size. Also, the bitmap `folderToZoom` is valid.

Comment: see https://pastebin.com/raw/zE5PHq1i

Comment: Thanks, but what is significant in that code that I don't have. I have done a bunch more experimenting and let me clarify that my SurfaceView blacks out the screen even if the animator code segment never executes. In other words, simply the creation of SurfaceView is failing. I'll update the post.

Comment: does the code i posted work? do you see moving and expanding bitmap? its hard to say whats significant as i dont see your code - you posted just two snippets

Comment: I haven't tried your code. It looks more or less like many examples I've seen and I'm sure they all work. As I stated above, the problem I'm having is creation of the SurfaceView. It is pointless to try displaying something on the view if it is not being created correctly. What I need is to determine why my creation is failing. Likely, I'll just have to keep stripping away parts of my app till it starts working, to identify what is causing the failure.